# ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecureRequestWarning' (PYTHON3 | RPI3 | gTTS)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip, text-to-speech, importerror

I'm having trouble using gTTS (Google Text to Speech) on my raspberry Pi 3. I simply did

```
sudo pip3 install gTTS
```

to install it. But when I run my code I find this error :

---

```
File "interface.py", line 7, in <module>

from gtts import *

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts/\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

from .tts import gTTS

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 4, in <module>
 from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecureRequestWarning'
```

---

To try to solve the problem I did

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pip
```

Then I have uninstalled and installed again gtts but the problem persists.

Thank you very much for your help ! :(

PS : I have installed python-vlc and mutagen to make working gTTS (as I did on a windows device)

Answer (score 7):

Just update `requests` library

```
pip install -U requests
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The `ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecureRequestWarning'` remains.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.`

```
import urllib3`
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Though it doesn't remove the entire warning message, still removes the Insecure Request Warning

Comment: After disabling the warnings the import error still remains: `ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecureRequestWarning'`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by running **pip install requests==2.6.0**

*if you face issue with bringing request library to 2.6.0 first remove pyopenssl and then run pip install requests==2.6.0*

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you still want to know but I can partially answer it.

```
import gtts
```

why this will work is because gtts automatically imports .tts and gTTS.

This is gtts.__init():

```
from .version import __version__
from .tts import gTTS
```

It's the only code in there.

You can go look yourself in the folder:
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts

OR

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtts

I am also trying to figure out still, how to use it but otherwise no.